# Overriding Bootstrap Breakpoints

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, media-queries, breakpoints

Bootstrap uses their set media queries to define their breakpoints.

I want to alter the breakpoints without going through and changing the px values in the bootstrap.min.css file.

Is there anyway to add a media query to my own css file that will override bootstrap's for example :
Bootstrap:

```
@media (min-width:992px) and (max-width:1199px){
    .visible-md-inline-block{
        display:inline-block!important
    }
}
```

Mine:

```
 @media (min-width:700px) and (max-width:1199px){
        .visible-md-inline-block{
            display:inline-block!important
        }
    }
```

Where the min width is expanded to allow lower pixel screens to view the page in a medium display.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could compile the CSS file locally or generate a custom one online:
http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Just change the Media query breakpoints and compile it.